# Logical Implication on set of statements

Tags: logic

All birds are animals. All animals are four legged. Implications

> a. All animals which are four legged are birds.
>
> b. All birds are four legged
>
> c. Some birds are four legged
>
> d. Some birds are animals but not four legged.
>
> **Choices**
>
> 1. a and b
> 2. b and c
> 3. only b
> 4. only d

What is the correct answer?

Answer (score 2):

a) is the converse, which doesn't follow. b) is true by modus ponens (or some call it hypothetical syllogism). It might seem c) is true, but in a universe having no birds it would be false. d) is directly false by the two hypotheses. So I'd go for "only b" though in a universe with at least one bird in it, c) would also be true.

Answer (score 1):

(3) is the correct answer.

We are given two "axioms":

1. $\forall x:[B(x)\implies A(x)]$
2. $\forall x:[A(x) \implies F(x)]$

where

$A(x)$ means $x$ is an animal

$B(x)$ means $x$ is a bird

$F(x)$ means $x$ is four-legged

It is trivial to prove (b) is true in general. The rest are not true in general.

If we have a "universe" consisting of only one element $x$, and $x$ is a four-legged animal, but not a bird, then both axioms will hold, but (a) will be false.

If we have a universe in which there are no animals or birds, then both axioms will hold vacuously, but (c) and (d) will be false.